# How can we use web3 with React to access a getter?

Tags: web3js

I had some working code but it seems standards moved.

I have some new code which fails.

```
componentWillMount () {

    var abi=
  [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"contractWeight","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"jsonInput","type":"string"},{"name":"hashKey","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"addContract","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"weight","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addWeight","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"contracts","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]

    var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/'));



    let commodityContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, this.state.contractAddress);
  //  let newContract =   commodityContract.at(this.state.contractAddress);
    this.setState({commodityContract: commodityContract});
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.coinbase;
    var test1 = '9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08';
  //  var testResult = commodityContract.contracts(test1);
  console.log(commodityContract);

}
```

Has anyone any idea about how to access a state variable (contracts) using web3?

Here is the smart contract -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract RegisterContract {

    uint public contractWeight;
    mapping(bytes32=>string) public contracts;

    function addContract ( string jsonInput, bytes32 hashKey) public {
        contracts[hashKey] = jsonInput;
    }

    function addWeight (uint weight) public {
        contractWeight = weight;
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems like this could work - now I get a promise -  commodityContract.methods.contracts(test2).call().then((result) => console.log(result)); I am unsure how to resolve a promise.

Answer (score 1):

```
let main = async () => {
    var abi=
  [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"contractWeight","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"jsonInput","type":"string"},{"name":"hashKey","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"addContract","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"weight","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addWeight","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"contracts","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]

    var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/'));
    var contractaddress= "0xb316b4bf742818d3fb97586a2f3aea361b240f30";


    let commodityContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractaddress);
  //  let newContract =   commodityContract.at(this.state.contractAddress);
  //  this.setState({commodityContract: commodityContract});
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.coinbase;
    var test1 = "0xf97f3f58a5fe44396d3abecdf8ec99639c2abf3e8c8117120234a5d705ceed93";
    var test2='0x9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08';
  //  var testResult = commodityContract.contracts(test1);
  var hexVal = web3.utils.asciiToHex(test1);
  var result='';
 commodityContract.methods.contracts(test1).call().then(
   (result) => console.log(result)
 );

  console.log(commodityContract);

}
```